# Flushing output with PHP ob_flush on Nginx/PHP-FPM

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to execute a PHP script which during execution provides the current status/percentage of completed actions. For do that I call the script with AJAX and I use the ob_flush for send the output to the client during script execution, it worked on Apache but now I'm porting the project on Nginx and I need compatibility for both. On Nginx I use PHP-FPM for handle PHP files, here's the test script which I'm trying to run correctly:

```
//SET CORRECT CONTENT-TYPE (THEY WILL BE JSON STRINGS SEPARED BY BREAKLINE)
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
//DISABLE GZIP FOR THE SCRIPT
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
ini_set('output_buffering', 'Off');
ini_set('output_handler', '');

ob_end_clean();
set_time_limit(0);

for ( $i = 0 ; $i < 5 ; $i++ ){
    echo "{\"code\":" . $i . "}\n";
    //SEND OUTPUT TO CLIENT
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

The problem is that when I run this I get the output just when the script ends the execution, so after about 5 seconds.
Someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look here - http://serverfault.com/q/488767

Comment: For now I've resolved overloading the buffer by adding some extra spaces to the message using the function `str_repeat(' ', 4096 * 8)`, it's a very inefficient and inelegant way to use flushing but it appears to be the only one with NGINX, anyway I have to give a look to the `fastcgi_keep_conn on;`" directive in the server configuration block in NGINX configuration file, maybe it can allows me to use normal PHP flush.

Answer (score 6):

You should set HTTP response header 'X-Accel-Buffering'
to 'no' when you don't want the Nginx to buffer the response
from FastCGI server.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_buffering

Comment: Calling header('X-Accel-Buffering: no'); in php script, or setting fastcgi_buffering: off; to turn off buffers globally.